# How do you upgrade mysql 4 to 5?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so im fairly new to this and i know some of you will point my to mysql page but im having a hard time finding specific and explicit directions on saying "To upgrade..do this..do that..done" and sites like mysql have a hard time conveying useful information to beginners.

I know it should be fairly simple, so can someone quickly lay down the steps on how to upgrade mysql from version 4 to 5 and upgrade from 5 to latest version with phpmyadmin? Also, are there certain versions of php that are incompatible with latest version of mysql? What should i do about that? Thank you so much?

Answer (score 3):

You could always consult dev.mysql.com:

- [General Update Information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading.html)
- [Upgrading to 5 from previous series](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)
- *Insert your version to 5 docs here*

Also, for dump-reload instructions, see [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html).

Comment: +1 for linking to the manual

Comment: i just asked people to explain it to me simply instead of refering me to the manual...

Comment: @Ben: No offense, but I draw a distinct line between making something more concise and spoon feeding. The dev docs, though long-winded at times, include all the information you could want/need. The last article I posted go over exporting the re-importing information. The version docs (i.e. v 4.x to 5.x) tell you anything you need to know about what may be deprecated, altered, removed and should keep in mind when transferring. Everything is right there, just set aside a few hours and read it through. If you have a specific "I tried this" question, someone will be more than willing to assist.